# No driver found for DataSource retrieved from JNDI

Tags: hibernate, maven, hana

I am trying to connect to HANA system using Jndiobject

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB" />
</bean>
```

Somewhere i am guessing I missed some maven dependency, because when i connect to local MySQL it works fine but when i change datasource like the above code i am getting the error mentioned below.

Please help.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/test] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2175)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2061)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:427)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:450)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.verifyUserDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.testhana.test.server.controller.ProduceUsersController.verifyUserDetails(ProduceUsersController.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: post your configuration class to your question

Answer (score 1):

Finally worked by adding HANAROW Dialect and the bean like below
Don't forget to open the tunnel to the SCP .

```
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value = "jdbc:sap://localhost:30015/?autocommit=false" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pass" />

</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path
>   [/test] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>   Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open
>   connection] with root cause java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

It says no driver found. Add the maven dependency of mysql.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.46</version>
</dependency>
```

If added you need to add the Driver to your hibernate configuration as well.

```
<property name = "hibernate.dialect">
     org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
</property>
<property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">
     com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
</property>
```

Or if your are using annotation based configuration then set the hibernate dialect to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` and driver to `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: I changed my dialect to hana since i am trying to connect to HANA by adding 
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HANARowStoreDialect</prop>
and the bean as
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:sap://localhost:30015/?autocommit=false" />
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver" />

Comment: try HANAColumnStoreDialect

Comment: Now i get a different error 
 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource

Comment: did you verfiy your presence of HANA driver

Comment: here's some driver related issue about HANA https://community.tableau.com/thread/135140

Comment: Search repositories in github https://github.com/chiranjeevibmse/user-jpa-hibernate-hana/tree/master/user-jpa-hibernate-hana

Comment: I have ngdbc.jar driver since this is need to connect HANA cloud system

Comment: Finally worked by adding HANARow Dialect and the bean like below

<bean id="dataSource"

  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value = "jdbc:sap://localhost:30015/?autocommit=false" />
  <property name="username" value="user" />
  <property name="password" value="pass" />

 </bean>